# Number of connected components of the complement of an image

Tags: general-topology

It is given that $f:\Bbb S^1 \mapsto \Bbb R^2$ is a continuous function such that $ f(a)=f(b)$ and $f$ is injective on $ \Bbb S^1$-$\{a\}$. I need to find the number of connected components of $\Bbb R^2 - f(\Bbb S^1)$. I am a bit confused here. $ \Bbb S^1$- $\{a\}$ is homeomorphic to the real line and $f(S^1)$ is compact. Since $f(b)=f(a)$, $f(S^1)$ will be mapped to a space homeomorphic to the real line which is not compact. Is there something wrong with my argument?

Comment: Do you know the Jordan curve theorem?

Comment: Sorry, I have not studied that theorem

Comment: The bit saying "$f(a) = f(b)$ and $f$ is injective on $\mathbb{S}^1-\{a\}$" just means that $f$ is injective almost everywhere. The only two points in $\mathbb{S}^1$ that are mapped to the same point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are  $a$ and $b$. Everything else is mapped to a distinct point.

Comment: @DanRust I do understand that. But the restriction of a continuous map is also continuous.

Comment: Yes but that's irrelevant to the problem. Given that description above, what do you imagine the image of $f$ looks like?

Comment: A non constant connected compact set.

Comment: I mean if you were to draw a picture, what picture would you draw? Can you draw one example of the image of such a function?

Comment: To answer your specific question about your argument, why should $f(\mathbb{S}^1)$ be homeomorphic to the real line? That's not true, as you point out by thinking about compactness.

Comment: I really cannot visualise how the image will look like. I understand there is some fallacy in my argument, since it is contradictory to the compactness of the circle; although I cannot find it specifically. What I am imagining is that the circle minus a point $a$ will be mapped to some open line segment in the plane and the point $a$ will also be mapped to the image of point $b$. This is surely not correct but I cannot point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: I think you're maybe getting lost in the notation of the problem. Can you see that a figure 8 drawing satisfies the conditions of such an $f$?

Comment: Am I correct if I say that the image of $\Bbb S^1$ and $\Bbb S^1 - \{a\}$ are the same?

Comment: yes, that's correct, because $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: I get the fallacy in my argument; a continuous bijection need not be a homeomorphism.